# How do I subscribe multiple S3 Lambda triggers to an existing bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

For example, we have three event subscribers (two for S3, one for HTTP.)

Currently, I am able to hit HTTP endpoint, However, unable to trigger s3 event as lambda is not attached to Bucket properties under Event section.

```yaml
functions:
   name: function-name
   handler: function-handler.handle
   events:
      - existingS3:
         bucket: abc-dev
         events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
         rules:
            - prefix: folder/my-folder
      - existingS3:
         bucket: abc-dev
         events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
         rules:
            - prefix: folder/my-folder-env
      - http:
         path: abc/xyz/
         method: post
         async: true
         private: true
```

Comment: Are you using a plugin? `existingS3` is not a valid event subscriber type by default.

Comment: yes i am using serverless-plugin-existing-s3 npm package..

Comment: That plugin is now deprecated due to changes in the serverless framework. See https://github.com/matt-filion/serverless-external-s3-event for details.

Comment: Tried With below changes and worked for me:
events:
      - s3:
         bucket: abc-dev
         events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
         rules:
            - prefix: folder/my-folder
  existing: true
      - s3:
         bucket: abc-dev
         events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
         rules:
            - prefix: folder/my-folder-env
  existing: true
      - http:
         path: abc/xyz/
         method: post
         async: true
         private: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Serverless Framework added support for existing S3 buckets last year. All you need to do is add a regular S3 event just like normal as documented but add the property `existing: true` to the configuration of the event.

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3#using-existing-buckets